# Can we perform an [operation] to excise this tag?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

[operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/operation)

No description, applied to a grand total of 706 questions across all sorts of technologies, most of which are low quality anyway. As such it seems like yet another one of those tags that was created for no other reason than someone felt like it that day.

1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

No, and no.

2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

In the same way that programming is.

3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

Absolutely not.

4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

Considering the variety of questions it's applied on, no.